How to concatenate variable and collection to string to use with label - Power Apps person field
I have a person field (Multiple selection).
When a user click and select a dropdown I need to do a lookup to grab the multi users from the person field and display them concatenated in a string.
On the onChange item in the dropdown I'm doing the below:
Set(
    varApprovers,
    LookUp(
        Group,
        ID = DataCardValue3_1.Selected.Id
    ).Approvers
);
ClearCollect(colOrderDistro,LookUp(
        Group,
        ID = DataCardValue3_1.Selected.Id
    ).Approvers);

I can see the collection and the variable table. But stuck on how to display the results in a string like so:
John Doe;Charles Dickson
Tried using this Concat(varApprovers,Value, ";").
But no luck.
Thanks in Advance.

Can you try this: Concat(varApprovers, DisplayName, ";")? Let me know if this works for you.

SharePoint people columns (person or group) has DisplayName property which shows the full name of users selected in column value.
So, try using your formula in Text property of label control like this:
Concat(varApprovers, DisplayName, ";")


Thanks Ganesh. It works . I knew I was missing something.
